# C#/LINQ if object doesnt contain id or code then get info form other object

Tags: c#, linq

Why is this not returning a string? I am trying to get the vehicleNumber from the _currentDriverData object that is contained in the Logs object.

```
var lookup = _currentDriverData.ToLookup(x => x.driverid);
                foreach (Logs log in _logsDutyStatusChange)
                {
                    if (lookup.Contains(log.did))
                    {
                        var vehicleNumber = lookup[log.did].Select(l => l.vehicle_number); ; 
                        log.trailerNumber = vehicleNumber;
                    }
                }
            }
```

it's saying vehicleNumber is a string array which cannot be converted to a string. How do I make this just a string?

Thanks

Comment: This looks like about the 5th question you've posted today about the same problem.  People might be able to be more helpful if you tell us what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: I am trying to learn it as I go not jsut get all the answers to the whole solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lookup[log.did].Select(l => l.vehicle_number).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

.Select brings back a collection if it finds more than one match in the query. You can use .First(), .FirstOrDefault() or .ToArray()/.ToList() and then grab whatever index makes sense.